PHP + Imagick - is it possible to draw shapes in batches instead of individually
I am writing a PHP script that uses the Imagick extension to draw random polygons to generate an image. In some cases, there are hundreds of polygons although the polygons are not overly complex (maximum 8 points). These polygons are all filled and use a color from a very limited color palette, usually no more than 4-8 different colours. The basic code looks like this:
public static function draw_polygon($points, $color)
{
    self::$draw->setFillColor($color);
    self::$draw->polygon($points);
}

This code is called every time a new polygon must be drawn. I have compared the script execution times with comparable code for GD and, for almost identical results, using Imagick is taking 3-4 times as long to generate the images, so I am looking for ways to optimize the drawing routines if possible.
If I use ImageMagick at the command line I could batch process the drawing to some extent by doing something like this:
convert -size 500x500 xc:white -draw "fill green polygon 400,300 200,120 128,120 340,360 fill red polygon 380,320 280,260, 200,250" polygons.gif

Batch processing the drawing operations in this way cuts down the number of times the convert tool needs to be called, therefore there should be less overhead/process usage rather than calling the convert tool once for each drawing operation. What I would like to know is whether it is possible or optimal to do this with Imagick? My understanding is that the Imagick extension interfaces with the local copy of ImageMagick on the server, therefore if I can batch process the drawing operations to same extent then there will be less overhead and hopefully the images can be generated faster.

"Imagick is taking 3-4 times as long to generate the images" Meaning what? 6 milliseconds instead of 2? Has this performance actually created a problem? This sounds like premature optimization.

Post the code for the polygon() function. Are you creating a new image object for each iteration of the points loop?

My "3-4 times as long" comment is a best case scenario, more complex images take much longer, maybe 5-10 times as long. The image generation is not taking milliseconds but seconds i.e. maybe 3-5 seconds to generate and save an image. The Imagick draw object is declared statically and the polygon vertices are pre-calculated before the script loops through all of the polygons to draw them. My code has identical routines for GD and yet everything is much faster.

OK, so $draw->polygon() is ImagickDraw::polygon()? You're not going to be able to improve on that by "batching", as it's already just a single function call, and not really comparable to shelling out to convert multiple times. If the performance of your GD implementation is so much better, why don't you use that? Or perhaps render SVG client-side?

Yes, that's correct. I do not know enough about the internals of Imagick to know how it is processing the drawing requests i.e. does it stack up all of the drawing operations until such time as I call drawImage() or does it keep shelling out to convert for each drawing operation? The GD output is fine but I also want to apply some effects which are not available in GD. The GD support is there as a fallback really. I should add that I am not processing the effects in the script at the moment, just drawing the main image.

It does not shell out at all, it's a native extension that calls the IMagick library code directly. You could draw the initial image with GD and then add the extra effects with IMagick.

Thank you for your suggestion, that would work. I'm hoping the performance will be better on the live server as it should have a newer version of ImageMagick and hopefully more processing power.
